# Since not all compact subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ are manifolds with boundaries, how can we this apply index of a vector field formula?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

My book is From Calculus to Cohomology by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave. I didn't study much of the definitions or theorems in Chapters 1 to 10 that might already be found in An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. I mostly assume the concepts are the same until there is evidence otherwise.

I believe I might have come across evidence that disproves one of my assumptions of equivalence of concepts. The assumption I made is:

> Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold with dimension. Let $N \subseteq M$. $N$ is what Madsen and Tornehave would call a "[domain with smooth boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV51k.png)" if and only if $N$ is what Tu would call a smooth $n$-manifold with boundary (see context below). $\tag{A}$

Now, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320464/can-every-compact-subset-of-mathbb-rn-be-realized-as-a-manifold-with-boundar) shows it is not necessarily the case that compact subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ can be realized as smooth manifolds with boundary. I assume this is not a dimension issue (see context below), so I guess I'll say that not all compact subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ can be realized as smooth **n-manifolds** (or **k-manifolds**) with boundary.

---

**Question:** (Definitions given below) Let $K$ be the compact set of [Lemma 11.25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRxw.png). How does the [proposition (the "(14)")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRxw.png) after [Lemma 11.25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRxw.png) apply [Corollary 11.23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbhwx.png) and thus [Theorem 11.22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbhwx.png) given $K$ is not stated to be a (compact) domain with smooth boundary while [Theorem 11.22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbhwx.png) assumes a domain with smooth boundary?

Possible answers:

1. $K$ disproves (A): $K$ is a domain with smooth boundary but not a smooth $n$-manifold with boundary.
2. $K$ does not disprove (A), but (A) is still false: $K$ is both a domain with smooth boundary and a smooth $n$-manifold with boundary, but, in general, domains with smooth boundary and smooth $n$-manifolds with boundary are not equivalent.
3. $K = \{||x|| \le 2\}$, and $K$ does not disprove (A), and (A) is true: $K$ is both a domain with smooth boundary and a smooth $n$-manifold with boundary.
4. $K \ne \{||x|| \le 2\}$, and $K$ does not disprove (A), and (A) is true: $K$ is both a domain with smooth boundary and a smooth $n$-manifold with boundary.
5. The proposition is incorrect and should have assumed $K$ is a (compact) domain with smooth boundary.

---

Context:

- On (A) and on dimensions:

  - [Definition 10.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV51k.png), the definition of "domain with smooth boundary" of Madsen and Tornehave.
  - [Tu Definition 22.6 (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iUIj.png) and [Tu Definition 22.6 (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmETl.png), of $n$-manifold with boundary (and manifold with boundary), where $\mathcal H^n := \{x \in \mathbb R^n | x_n \ge 0\}$.
  - Note that Madsen and Tornehave have $x_1 \le 0$ while Tu has $x_n \ge 0$.
  - Also note that Tu's manifolds are not the same as his $n$-manifolds because not all his manifolds' connected components have the same dimension (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146131/is-0-1-cup-2-a-manifold-with-boundary-my-issue-is-the-2) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273320/can-a-topological-manifold-be-non-connected-and-each-component-with-different-di)), but for Madsen and Tornehave, I believe their manifolds and domains with smooth boundary have (uniform) dimensions.
- Definitions of index: [Definition 11.16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5iSn.png), [Definition 11.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vApbr.png), [Definition 11.21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLfF4.png)

Comment: 2.) Is false. Plenty of compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are not manifolds at all, and thus are not domains with smooth boundary.

Comment: From my cursory reading, the only way that (A) could be false is if there were some technical difference between the author's definitions of submanifold.

Comment: @RyleeLyman Oh I just edited the post. Thanks. Anyway, I took that off already.

Comment: @RyleeLyman Thanks! I guess this isn't a technical difference issue, then.

Comment: @RyleeLyman Wait the conjecture in the previous edit was that I know not all compact subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ are $k$-manifolds with or without boundary, but perhaps they are domains with smooth boundary thus disproving the equivalence in $(A)$. Also, if $(A)$ is true, then why does not manifold without boundary imply not a manifold with boundary? I think it should be the converse: Not a manifold with boundary implies not a manifold without boundary.

Comment: @RyleeLyman Wait, is $K =\{||x|| \le 2\}$?

Comment: this $K$ is both an $n$-manifold with boundary and a smooth domain with boundary. I think it's apparent that it would help you to figure out why.

Comment: @RyleeLyman So we can actually strengthen Lemma 11.25 from "compact set" to "compact domain with smooth boundary"? Thanks!

Comment: This would be a **weakening** of Lemma 11.25. Compact domains with smooth boundary in particular have nonempty interior, while arbitrary compact sets do not have to have nonempty interior. :)

Comment: @RyleeLyman Why am I weakening? I mean that Lemma 11.25 says $F|_K^c = F|_K^c$ for a compact set $K$. If I were to say that $F|_K^c = F|_K^c$ for a compact set $K$ that is also a compact manifold with boundary, then it sounds like I am saying more. Also, are you talking about topological interior for both?

Comment: @RyleeLyman Saying more is strengthening, or not actually?